# I imported the Collada file into Blender, after I import it why is there a vertices in solid mode?

Tags: mesh, objects, 3d-view, vertices, collada

[image: the screen i have]I imported the Collada file into Blender, after I import it why is there a vertices in solid mode? even though I unchecked the wireframe option in the viewport display. can it be deleted, if possible please show how? thank you

Comment: did you turn off geometry > wireframe in the viewport overlays menu in the top right of viewport?

Answer (score 0):

Just select all the vertices in *Edit Mode* and merge them (press <kbd>M</kbd>, and choose *By Distance*).